# Javascript value to MySQL Select

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp-classic

I have form with select and options to choose from.
select option values are brought up by asp classic loop.

The second select is filled from javascript based on what first select value has been made.
Then it sends the value out by

```
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.value = "2015";
newOption.innerHTML = "Year";
s2.options.add(newOption);
```

So now i want to expand where it will bring mysql recordset (without submitting yet) based on what second select choice have been made

```
Set package = ObjConn.execute ("Select * from pack_plan where idpack = "JS.value??"")
```

So i want to be able to receive the value and select records from it. And i have no idea how this will be done. Help appreciated.

Comment: You would need to send `JS.value` to the server, either in a querystring or as a form variable, as your classic asp code is rendered on the server before the page loads and your JS is rendered by the browser after the page loads.  Maybe there's a way to do this with an ajax call, (ajax isn't something I've really gotten into to date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works fine for me.
Since you probably don't want to reload the page you need to make an asynchronous request to retrieve the values of a second select according to the choice the user makes on first select. 
So on your page you will have the form with the selects and a few lines of javascript that will make the asynchronous call.

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function jsfunc1(primaryjsvalue){
  $.ajax({url:"http://www.yoursite.com/secondary_list.asp?reqvalue="+primaryjsvalue.value, success:function(result){
 if (result == "errore") {
    $("#thesecondarylist").html('Error');
} else {
    $("#thesecondarylist").html(result);
}
}});
}
</script>

<select id="selectid1" name="primaryselect" onchange="jsfunc1(this)">
  <option value="val1" id="valid1"> Val1 </option>
  <option value="val2" id="valid2"> Val2 </option>
  <option value="val3" id="valid3"> Val3 </option>
</select>

<div id="thesecondarylist">
<select id="selectid2" name="secondaryselect" >
  <option value="" id=""> Choose from primary list to see available values </option>
</select>
</div>
```

The secondary_list.asp page will query the db according to the option selected on the main page,
and will loop each value writing a response that will be the content of the "thesecondarylist" div.

So will contain only the code to Open the connection, query the DB and print the second select option filled from db.

Your asp file can directly start with:

Basically your code

```
Set package = ObjConn.execute ("Select * from pack_plan where idpack = "JS.value??"")
```

become

```
Set package = ObjConn.execute ("Select * from pack_plan where idpack = "&Request.QueryString("reqvalue")&"")
'... retrieve your records ...
%>
<select id="selectid2" name="secondaryselect" >
<%
while not rsSecondList.EOF
    theValue = rsSecondList("packname")
    theId = rsSecondList("idpack")
%>
<option value="<%=theValue%>" id="<%=theId%>"> <%=theValue%> </option>
<%
rsSecondList.Movenext
Wend
%>
</select>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, hade to change the rsSecondList to package.eof and rsSecondList.Movenext to package.Movenext then it worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, I'm happy it helped. To make it perfect I suggest you to care about security making some checks on the QueryString data to avoid sql injection. (Replace quotes, stop sql commands, verify data type...)